# Angular 16 issue with ng-openapi-gen

Tags: angular, openapi-generator

I have an issue with ng-openapi-gen and angular 16 I do not understand.

I have an api I have generated the client part from my server using ng-open-api.
I created the ng app and trying to use the API.

When in **app.component.ts** I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService} from './api/services/api.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngClient';
  }
```

All works fine and when I am adding the constructor like shown below:

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngClient';
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {  }
}
...
```

The html page does not show anymore with errors in browser dev tools:
[image: errors]

Did anyone faced this already?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved modifying **app.module.ts** like shown below:

```
...
    import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    ApiModule.forRoot({ rootUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api' }),
```